# How to identify a throwable with specific data

Tags: java

I have this caught that catches any uncaught exception

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
   }
});
```

Inside the method, I want to deal with following exception differently than other exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.company.si.stats.Statistics.hashString(Statistics.java:192)
    at com.company.si.stats.Statistics.sendStatistics(Statistics.java:127)
```

I want basically to check that it is nullpointer exception coming from `com.company.si.stats.Statistics.hashString`

How can I do that? I am not sure what parameters in throwable I should compare against?

The code where exception is thrown was not written by me, so I cannot change anything about it.

**Important NOTE**
I know the way I am approaching this problem is not the right way. But I dont have access to the library raising the exception and I needed a workaround till the bug is fixed in the library. The answer was chosen because it satisfies what I need to, and not what generally should be dne

Comment: It's probably possible using `e.getStackTrace()`, but surely there is a better way to handle the problem at those actual lines?

Comment: @4castle this is a really bad idea. Code changes, and hardcoding values such as line numbers or method names to handle specific exceptions could cause bugs that would be really annoying to deal with.

Comment: @Jezor Right, I'm not condoning they do that. Ultimately, they need to prevent the `NullPointerException` from the start.

Comment: I have no access to this file as it is library.  It has an error, until they fix this error I would like some work around. So I am ok with the "bad solution" for now. I just don't know how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Disclaimer

This was suggested in the comments and I thought it will be a good idea to add it as an answer, but remember that **this is not how you should do it, so please use this answer as an example of how NOT to handle this type of problem**. Feel free to also downvote it.

---

You can check where the exception comes from by [looking at its stack trace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()), or at least at first stack trace element.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
   @Override
   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
       StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = e.getStackTrace();
       if (e instanceof NullPointerException &&
           stackTrace != null && stackTrace.length >= 0 &&
           "Statistics.java".equals(stackTrace[0].getFileName()) &&
           "hashString".equals(stackTrace[0].getMethodName()) &&
           192 == stackTrace[0].getLineNumber()) {
           // Handle your exception here.
       }
   }
});
```

Reasons why you should **not** do it:

1. it's really ugly
2. any change in `hashString` method will make this useless
3. because mom said so
4. any change in `Statistics` class will make this useless
5. in case of 2 or 4, finding bugs caused by this exception could be really painful
6. it's not portable (think about changing the library in the future)
7. it's bad practice

Comment: @Snake oh my, once again, this is **the wrong** answer!!! You made me sad by accepting it instead of the other one ):

Comment: This answers my specific question. I know it is wrong, but clearly stated in the question that I know it is wrong approach but I have reason for it. It will help someone to understand how to parse  exceptions though :)

Comment: @Snake after edit, my other answer can be used to solve your problem as well, in a more sophisticated and clear way. But oh well, you are the one to decide :P

Comment: even the edited answer don't solve the problem. Because I am not calling the hashstring method. It is being called internally by the library that's why I am catching it in the generic exception catcher

Comment: @Snake but you have to call something that calls it, and you can wrap that call in `try-catch` block to translate the exception (:

Comment: I wish it was that. I call a library that uploads  the file. This library starts a timertask on another task (my guess) which calls that method. Surrounding the orginal call with try catch didn't catch it as it is another thread/process. Thus why I catch it in the generic catch block for the whole app

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own exception, for instance:

```
public class HashingException extends RuntimeException {
    public HashingException(Throwable t) {
        super(t);
    }
}
```

As you said, the `com.company.si.stats.Statistics.hashString()` method wasn't made by you so you can't change it. But [you can translate the exception thrown by it](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=120). I'm not sure how the method signature looks like, but here's how you can do it:

```
// ... some code, Statistics object initialization somewhere

String hashString;

try {
    hashString = statistics.hashString(someArgumentMaybe);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new HashingException(e);
}

// result of method is available here as hashString object
```

and later handle it in your `handler` class like:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (e instanceof HashingException) {
            HashingException hashingException = (HashingException) e;
            // Handle your exception here.
            Exception cause = e.getCause();
            // cause will be NullPointerException
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I have no access to the file generating that exception. It is a bug and until they fix it, I need to do a work around. So your answer wouldnt solve my problem thats why I was asking how to hardcode detection of the "file it happens at" and the "null pointer" but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to get your stacktrace as a String or a reader

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stacktraceContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(stacktraceContent));
try (BufferedReader reader =
   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new
   ByteArrayInputStream(stacktraceContent.toByteArray())))) {
   // Here you can read your stacktrace line by line and match against any 
   // pattern
}
```

Also there is a nice Open Source library that filters logs. Its called MgntUtils library. Here you can find an article describing it in detail:

[Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles). The article also provides links to github (source) and Maven where you can download it or integrate it into your Maven project. Here are the links anyway: [MgntUtils on github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) and [Maven link](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.michaelgantman%22%20AND%20a%3A%22MgntUtils%22)